# How can I give up local commit in Github in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I use Github in my project. I do the error commit in locally, they are "Submit 4 Error" and "Submit 5 Error".

I hope to give up the two error local commit, and don't push the two error commit to remote repository, how can I do in Android Studio?

**Figure**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean **TOTALLY** discard those two commits (**WARNING: YOU WILL LOSE THE CODE ENTIRELY!**), you can use `git reset --hard` on that commit.

Right click on the last commit you want to keep (for your picture, Submit 3), `Reset Current Branch to Here...` -> `Hard`.